# How do I parse HTML email using PHP IMAP?

Tags: php, html-parsing, imap

I'm trying to parse HTML data in an email using PHP's IMAP functions.

When I `echo imap_body($Mailbox, 1);` by example, the HTMl contained inside seems to be converted into
a different encoding (MIME I suspect)

Here is a sample chunk of `$body`:

```
<TH=20
      style=3D"PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; PADDING-BOTTOM: =
5px; COLOR: #fff; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #6eafd0 1px solid; =
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #004454"=20
      align=3Dleft>Site</TH>
```

How do I convert the received the body data into parsable HTML ?

Thank you

Comment: What should be the end result? Do you want to re-display it as an HTML page or are extracting certain parts for a database? More info please.

Comment: @Anriëtte, thank you for your comment. I believe my last line say it all: I want to extract the information in HTML so I can parse it later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, looks old MIMEish.  Perhaps try `$decoded = quoted_printable_decode ( $body );`

The "3D" part is a give away: "US-ASCII equal sign (decimal value 61) must be represented by '=3D'". ( [wiki on quoted-printable encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)).

Comment: Nice, Learn something new everyday, +1